# How android services callbacks get called?

Tags: android

How android services callbacks getting called automatically when **startService() or bindService()** method call from any Android component?

Comment: Please tell me the internal procedure of Android services. It means the flow of Android services which called the service callbacks.

Comment: ok. Android service has own lifecycle method these methods I am considering callback. For example, I created service as startService then how lifecycle methods triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To communicate with Service from an activity just by using method startService() and passing Intent to the argument in the method, or either we can use bindService() to bind the service to the activity with argument Intent.

Also when I was new to Android and anyone had asked me how to make Synchronous calls with Service then my answer is like First, we will start service and we define our custom Action with BroadCastReceiver and when action is sent then BroadCastReceiver can be used to start the activity.
By using Callback implementation in Service you can get instant results of the operation that is being performed in Service, in onBind() you can get the instance of Service and once you have the instance of the service you call its method which processes the task. and you can set the Callbacks during those process and the response of the call back in Activity can be used to update the UI for the User.